# How do I handle errors

Tags: python, stripe-payments

The Stripe API has an example of how to switch a customer's subscription: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/upgrading-downgrading

```
# Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
# See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2"

subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve('sub_49ty4767H20z6a')
stripe.Subscription.modify('sub_49ty4767H20z6a',
  items=[{
    'id': subscription['items']['data'][0].id,
    'plan': 'plan_CBb6IXqvTLXp3f',
  }]
)
```

How would I write an error-handling block for this code in cases where there's a problem charging the customer's credit card?

Comment: You need to know what the api response is for problems.  Then you can create an error handling block..

Comment: Subscription payments happen asynchronously (outside of the scope of your code).  You'd need to wait for `invoice.payment.failed` webhook events.  You could wrap that modify in a try-catch block though.

Answer (score 2):

https://stripe.com/docs/api#error_handling

This article has a sample on how to do error handling with their python lib